# Loading XML File which is in classpath in Java

Tags: java, xml, resources, classpath

I need to load a xml file present in classpath into my java applicatio. Can any one give suggestions on this.

Thanks,
Narendra

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) or [`Class.getResourceAsStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)), and then load it as you would for any other `InputStream`.

(The difference between using the `ClassLoader` version and the `Class` version is how "relative" resource paths are resolved. With the `ClassLoader` version, it's always effectively treated as an absolute path; with the `Class` version, if the path doesn't start with "/" it's treated as relative to the package of that class.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am able to load the file and read it as InputStream. Now My problem is I need to load this file to validate a xml file(i.e schema validation). For doing this I am using following code snippet. 

 SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(schemaInstance);

      Schema schema = factory.newSchema(scheam);
      Validator xmlValidator = schema.newValidator();
For creating schema i need instance of schema file and i need to load accrding to classpath.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: @Narendra: I'm afraid I haven't done much work with schemas, but you could create a `StreamSource` from an `InputStream` and call `factory.newSchema(streamSource)`.